# Alternative facts in Japanese

Tags: translation

Recently, in the US the word 'alternative facts' have prompted a lot of discussion. I wonder what this phase is known in Japanese. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

It is most commonly known as 「もう一{ひと}つの真実{しんじつ}」.

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86%E4%B8%80%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E4%BA%8B%E5%AE%9F

Comment: リンク先の題名は「もう一つの事実」のようですが…